# how to connect  windows phone 7 application by using 2 different mobile device?

Tags: xna-4.0

I currently create a SL/XNA application.How should I do if the user A want to connect to user B through the application?

Comment: I agree with N Taylor's answer. These are both viable options. One thing to keep in mind though is that your communications are not going directly from phone A to phone B. Your services need to be hosted on some sort of server and that will act as the middle man and you will communicate through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways you can do this:

1. Create web services that both phones connect to and build logic to allow the two to communicate via the services.

   Ex: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg241261.aspx
2. Use SignalR to allow both phones to talk to each other in real time. You can open up the SignalR WP7 solution and take a look.

   Example: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-SignalR-Awesome-Possibilities.aspx

   Github: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/

   Wiki: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki

Hope this helps!